# How do I change the owner of a board or organization in Trello?

Tags: trello

I need to transfer ownership of my board/organization.

I set it up but now need to pass the day-to-day management of the board onto the people who'll actually be using it.

How do I do this?

Comment: You don't really need to declare yourself in questions - just answers. It would also be better if you just waited for the questions to come and answer organically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose Alice wants to give up control of an **organization**, and have Bob be the new organization administrator.

1. If necessary, Alice should add Bob to the organization
2. From the organization's members page (e.g. https://trello.com/examples/members), Alice should click on Bob's avatar, and select **"Make Admin of Organization"**
3. Alice should click on her own avatar and select **"Give up Ownership of Organization"**

Suppose instead that Alice wants to give up control of a **board**, and have Bob be the new board owner.

1. If necessary, Alice should invite Bob to the board, and Bob should accept the invitations.
2. Alice should click Bob's avatar in the Members section of the board.  In the dialog that pops up, Alice should click the **"Make Co-Owner"** button (on the right)
3. Alice should click her own avatar, and in the dialog that pops up click the **"Give up co-ownership"** link (on the right)

Comment: Looks like the UI for this has changed a bit.  Now you click on the avatar, select `Change permissions`, and select `Admin` to elevate another user.  They still have to be a member first.  Then the new admin can log in, click on the old admin's avatar, and demote them to a regular user, or remove them, or the old admin can remove themselves, or stay on as a regular member.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer above addresses only the issue of changing organization ownership, not changing board (co-)ownership.  The answer to [deleting the trello user from your project](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18990/delete-the-trello-user-from-your-project) would seem to answer this as well, except that it didn't work for me in that specific case.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include instructions for changing the ownership of a board