# Removing the built-in "Trello" user from a project

Tags: trello

When I create a new project the Trello user seems to be automatically added.

How do I delete the Trello user from projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Trello user is only auto-added to your initial Welcome Board, not to other boards you create.

However, when I tried [Rich's instructions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18990/delete-the-trello-user-from-your-project/18999#18999), the board activity popup for the trello user had only the View Profile button, not the Make Co-owner (it already is co-owner) or Remove from Board options.

Now it is possible that this has something to do with my having archived all the lists on the Welcome Board and closed my Welcome Board itself (I re-opened it to test this out, of course).  I would be curious if others have the same difficulty with removing other co-owners, or the trello user/co-owner specifically.

Comment: Ah okay thanks that helps! I didn't understand that part.

Comment: The Trello user is no longer the co-owner of the Welcome Board, so Rich's instructions should work

Answer (score 7):

Click on the member icon at the upper right.

[image: Click User]

Click **Remove from board**.

[image: Remove From Board]

If this is not what you're talking about, please contact us on the Trello team directly at `support@trello.com`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the welcome board one auto - added the trello user, but my future boards are working perfectly fine now.