# How to remove oneself from a Trello board?

Tags: trello, delete

Upon receiving an invite to a board and accepting, I am unable to find a way to remove myself from that board. The only way for me to be removed is to contact the original creator of the board and have them remove me (ala [Removing the built-in "Trello" user from a project](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18990/deleting-the-trello-user-from-a-project/18999#18999))

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to the board
2. Left-click on your avatar in the "Members" section
3. In the menu that pops up, click "Leave Board"

[image: Leave Board]

Comment: Sure enough, I was missing something. Intuition was drawing me to the Boards view. From that view I can unpin a board from my menu. It would make sense to be able to remove it entirely from that same view as well.